# Header background image height not working

Tags: html, css

When I have this picture in it only goes a certain amount of height and it wont go past. If you make it smaller it will become smaller, but if you make it bugger it wont be bigger then 50px.

Code:

Hmtl

```
  <body>
  <div class="header-img">
<div id="wrapper">   
   <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    Rx Programming
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Calender</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Achievements</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Trainer</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Social</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Account</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sign Out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">


        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default btn-right"  id="menu-toggle">Menu</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
<script>
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.btn .btn-default .btn-right {
padding: 20px;
color: red !important;
float: left;
}


.header-img {
background-image: url(../img/crossfitheader.jpg);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #222;
height: 100%

}

#wrapper {
padding-left: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
z-index: 1000;
position: fixed;
left: 250px;
width: 0;
height: 100%;
margin-left: -250px;
overflow-y: auto;
background: #000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
position: absolute;
margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 250px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
text-indent: 20px;
line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
height: 65px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
color: #fff;
background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
}
}

.btn .btn-default .btn-right {
padding: 20px;
color: red !important;
}

#menu-toggle {
padding: 20px;
color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing... can you please be more specific and show us a jsfiddle example?

Comment: It's definitely unclear what you're asking.  Perhaps you're looking for the CSS `background-size:cover;` or `background-size:100%;` ?  More information about background-size can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear and I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, though I'm assuming you're trying to enlarge an image if the window size is expanded or decreased?

Simple line in your stylesheet can fix this (IF this is what you're asking..)

```
img{max-width:100%;height:auto;}
```

All it dose is set the height of the image automatically and give it a responsive quality.